# How to use MS SQL STUFF with subselect?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am building a simple news site in with MS SQL as db. Authors can tag each news item to categorize content. I have a page where I list all headlines related to a specific tag, e.g.

```
www.example.org/tag/tag1

Headline 1
Headline 2
...
```

On that page I also want to show all other tags related to the specific news item like so:

```
www.example.org/tag/tag1

Headline 1
[tag1] [tag2] -- show all related tags to each news item

Headline 2
[tag1] [tag3]
```

I figured I need to use SQL STUFF and sub select but it is not working as intended.

When I run SQL code below I get the following:

```
Headline 1  computer, computer, business, general
Headline 2  computer, computer, business, general
```

but what I really want is:

```
Headline 1  computer, business
Headline 2  computer, general
```

What is wrong with my SQL?

```
-- create table structure
create table #news (
    newsid int,
    title nvarchar(256)
)

create table #tags (
    tagid int,
    title nvarchar(128)
)

create table #newstags (
    newsid int,
    tagid int
)

-- load data    
insert into #news values (1,'Headline 1')
insert into #news values (2,'Headline 2')

insert into #tags values (1,'computer')
insert into #tags values (2,'business')
insert into #tags values (3,'general')

insert into #newstags values (1,1) -- Headline 1, computer
insert into #newstags values (1,2) -- Headline 1, business
insert into #newstags values (2,1) -- Headline 2, computer
insert into #newstags values (2,3) -- Headline 2, general

declare @tagid int = 1

-- select results    
select 
    NewsId
    ,Title
    ,STUFF(
            (
                SELECT 
                    ', ' + CAST(title AS nvarchar(64)) + ' [tagid:' + CAST(TagId AS nvarchar(64))+']' [text()]
                FROM 
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            n.NewsId
                            ,nt.TagId
                            ,t.title
                        FROM #news n
                            INNER JOIN #newstags nt ON n.newsid = nt.newsid
                            INNER JOIN #tags t ON nt.tagId = t.TagId
                        WHERE n.newsid IN
                            (SELECT #newstags.newsid FROM #newstags WHERE tagid = @tagid)
                    ) AS TempTable
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,''
         ) AS TagsCombined
from #news

-- clean up
drop table #news
drop table #tags
drop table #newstags
```

Comment: Way to go on posting proper sample data and expected results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery is a little over-complicated and it's not co-related to the main query.
Here's a revised version (I've included some remarks in the code where I've changed things):

```
SELECT 
    n.NewsId
    ,Title
    ,STUFF(
            (
                SELECT 
                    -- title is already nvarchar, no need to cast
                    -- TagId is an int - the maximum number of chars needed is 11 
                    -- (enough to cover it's minimum value including the minus sign)
                    ', ' + title + ' [tagid:' + CAST(TagId AS nvarchar(11))+']' [text()]
                FROM 
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            nti.NewsId
                            ,nti.TagId
                            ,t.title
                        -- no need to select from #news here as well
                        FROM #newstags AS nti 
                        INNER JOIN #tags AS t 
                            ON nti.tagId = t.TagId
                        -- here's the relation to the main query
                        WHERE nti.newsid = n.newsid
                        --If you want all tags except the main one unremark the next row:
                        -- AND t.TagId <> @TagId
                    ) AS TempTable
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,''
         ) AS TagsCombined
FROM #news AS n
INNER JOIN #newstags AS nto ON n.NewsId = nto.NewsId
WHERE nto.TagId = @TagId
```

Comment: Works perfect and thanks for including code optimizations as well! Thank you.